# Why does makenote not work if I have loaded the tikz package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scrlayer-notecolumn

I was going to asked a question about how tikz and `scrlayer-notecolumn` interacted.
But it seems like in my MWE they can't even be used in the same document.
I know that is not true as in my main document I am using both.
But here is the MWE:

### Without tikz

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}

\begin{document}
Hello and welcome
\makenote{Just a note}
\kant[1]
\makenote{A second note}
\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

The output, as expected is:
[image: Expected outout]

### With `usepackage{tikz}`

Code is identical except uncomment out the `usepackage{tikz}` line.

the output is now:
[image: fail output]

Where did my notes go?
I've tried building a few times and clearing all .snlc files and aux files,
but it seems like in this case it just doesn't work.
Its not like tikz  is even being used for anything in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `scrlayer-notecolumn`:

> Package scrlayer-notecolumn should solve all these problems. To do so, it uses the basic
>   functionality of scrlayer. Nevertheless, there is a disadvantage of using this package: Notes
>   can be output only on pages that use a scrlayer based page style. This disadvantage may be
>   easily resolved and maybe changed into an advantage using scrlayer-scrpage.

So you have to load/use package `scrlayer-scrpage` to ensure that a layer pagestyle is used:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\begin{document}
Hello and welcome
\makenote{Just a note}
\kant[1]
\makenote{A second note}
\kant[2]
\section{A section}
\kant
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Note that `scrlayer-scrpage` redefines pagestyles `headings` and `plain` as aliase of the layer pagestyles `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings` respectively. And it activates pagestyle `scrheadings`.

---

**Additional explanation:**

Package `scrlayer-notecolumn` bases (and loads) on package `scrlayer` which automatically redefines pagestyle `empty` as a layer page style.

With

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\begin{document}
Hello and welcome
\makenote{Just a note}
\kant[1]
\makenote{A second note}
\kant[2]
\section{A section}
\kant
\end{document}
```

you would get the warning

> Package scrlayer-notecolumn Warning: \clearnotecolumns while active non-layer page style.
>   (scrlayer-notecolumn)                Activate empty page style until note column
>   (scrlayer-notecolumn)                has been cleared on input line 14.

At the end of the document a `\clearnotecolumns` is executed automatically and the notes are on the last page which uses pagestyle `empty`. I am sure that this is also not a desired result.

It seems that package `tikz` prevents the automatical execution of `\clearnotecolumns` at the end of the document. But if you add this command at the end of the document

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\begin{document}
Hello and welcome
\makenote{Just a note}
\kant[1]
\makenote{A second note}
\kant[2]
\section{A section}
\kant
\clearnotecolumns
\end{document}
```

you will get the same result as above: notes are on the last page and this page uses pagestyle `empty`.

I do not recommended, but you can try to change the pagestyle manuelly:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\begin{document}
Hello and welcome
\makenote{Just a note}\thispagestyle{empty}
\kant[1]
\makenote{A second note}\thispagestyle{empty}
\kant[2]
\section{A section}
\kant
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but why does it work? Shouldn't this have nothing to do with tikz? i.e. it should fail whether or not `usepackage{tikz}` was done?

Comment: See my updated answer. As you can see in the additional example it also does not work in the expected way even if package `tikz` is not loaded.